# Trouble with Instafeed.js

Tags: javascript, instagram

I am just creating a basic page that shows Photos from Instagram using the Instafeed.js library. I followed the tutorial but when I open my HTML page, I just see pixilated images and not the actual images.

When I open the console, I get the error net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND  next to each photo.

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="instafeed.min.js"></script>


<div id="instafeed"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
 var feed = new Instafeed({
    get: 'tagged',
    tagName: 'awesome',
    clientId: 'Your Client Id'
});
 feed.run();
</script>
```

Comment: If you are looking for a workaround for the new API after March 31 2020, look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60394300/2397550

Answer (score 5):

If you are viewing your HTML page locally (and by locally I mean your address bar begins with `file://`, you will need to add `useHttp: true` to your settings:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var feed = new Instafeed({
    get: 'tagged',
    tagName: 'awesome',
    clientId: 'Your Client Id',
    useHttp: true   // <--- add this
  });
  feed.run();
</script>
```

---

This option is required when viewing files locally since the images are trying to load using [protocol-relative URLs](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/). If you were to view that HTML file on an actual web server, that option isn't required.

That change was introduced in version [1.3](https://github.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js/releases/tag/v1.3.0).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem matey, inspecting the elments will help a lot. Adding the template param will help and the problem is with the {{image}} you have to put http: before it. Hope it helps because it should.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var feed = new Instafeed({
 get: 'tagged',
 tagName: 'awesome',
 clientId: 'Your Client Id',

 template: '<a href="{{link}}" target="_blank"><img src="http:{{image}}" /></a>'
```

Comment: You actually can just add the `useHttp: true` option. You don't have to add `http:` to the template. Check my answer above for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue. Even after following Steven's answer I could not get the images to display locally. However, after uploading the file to the server all images appeared as expected. You have to make sure that the client id you use is correct and try to access it on the server. My code looked like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var feed = new Instafeed({
  get: 'tagged',
  tagName: 'happy',
  clientId: 'the-client-id'
  });
  feed.run();
</script>
 <div id="instafeed"></div>
</body>
```